# Is it possible to have a second profile in Bad Piggies?

Tags: bad-piggies

I played through BP and got 3 stars everywhere. I'd like to keep that profile/savegame, so I can continue when new content is released.

But now my gf wants to play too, and it's a bit boring for her, since she can always see my solution when she restarts my already finished levels.

So, is it possible to have a second profile or savegame?
I didn't see anything to switch (or even reset) in the options, but perhaps I missed it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to have a second profile, but you can always back up your save game and then delete the save game files.  [There's a handy article that specifies how to back up bad piggies on any platform](http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/bad-piggies-ultimate-backup-tutorial-for-all-platforms/#android).

For ios, the directions are to download an iOS file explorer (like DiskAid or iExplorer) and retrieve the following files from `Apps > Bad Piggies > Documents`:

- Achievements.xml
- Settings.xml
- Progress.dat
- contraptions (the folder and all of its contents)

To restore your save game, just copy the backup files over the ones in your iOS folder.

Answer (score 1):

For those playing this on Windows PC, the files are located in

C:\Users\"user account"\AppData\LocalLow\Rovio\Bad Piggies

Answer (score 0):

I made a profile manager for Bad Piggies. It's basic.

http://sandbox.yoyogames.com/games/229629-bad-piggies-profile-manager

There is a bug where the backup button won't work until you activate a profile.

This means you must activate a profile, and leave the program running. Then click backup to save your progress when your done.

This is really only useful on windows

Comment: Nice program, but it doesn't answer whether it is possible to have multiple profiles in Bad Piggies.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can have a second profile. You do it by having different Windows 7 users. You have to add the activation key on for each user.

Comment: This question is asking specifically about the iOS version.